# Which method is called of previous activity if i called finish of current activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my Application I have two activity , in first activity i have Recycleview, IN second activity I am updating my database and then called finish for go back to my listview, So my question is in which method should i put Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() for get my updated Recycleview.

**Some Important code:**

**Calling Finish() in second activity:**

Naviagtion ICon of toolbar event handle below code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // handle arrow click here
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {

            finish(); // close this activity and return to preview activity (if there is any)
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It invokes the onResume() of the previous activity, if the previous activity has not been finished, as shown in the Activity Lifecycle diagram on Android Developer Documentation. [Source](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle).

Answer (score 0):

When the activity opens back up, it will call and `OnResume()`. 
This is explained in the android documentation
[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

You should update your RecycleView like this

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
   super.onResume();
   myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onRestart(){
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
super.onRestart();
}
```

EDIT:

In your second activity, if database updated add a flag to sharedpreference like below

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
sharedpreference.edit().putBoolean("isModified",true).apply();
//Or flase if not modified
 super.onDestroy();
}
```

In First Activity

```
@Override
    public void onRestart(){
    super.onRestart();
if(sharedpreference.getBoolean("isModified",false)){
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
sharedpreference.edit().putBoolean("isModified",flase).apply();
}
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but still the same but because of that i was able to understand problem , I solved that by only Reading database again before notifyDataSetChanged().